# What is the maximum height I can go above the roof of my house

Tags: united-states, legal

I have a new 5/8 wave Antenna with 3 radials. It's just over 22 feet high, the mast-pole is 30 foot long and will be mounted on the side of my house question is, what is the maximum "legal" height I can go above the roof of my house. 73

Comment: The answer to this depends on city ordinances.  The only thing in part 97 about this would depend on you being near an airport, which would restrict it more.

Comment: Hi everyone, I Did find this on the Gov. website..

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and indicate what country you are in.

Answer (score 4):

This answer applies to the United States. I have no idea about restrictions in other countries.

The FAA has regulations for antennas higher than 200 feet with regards to needing marker lights and will also limit antennas near airports.

There are also numerous restrictions imposed by state, county, and city ordnances and building codes. If you live within city limits, I would suggest contacting your city government about building codes. If not within city limits, I would contact the county.

A local HAM club may also be able to provide advice, but I would still check with local government for any antenna that will be significantly higher than the roof line.

There may also be restrictions from other groups such as HOAs.

Comment: @10-10 - hmmmm.... somebody else added the united-states tag. Perhaps you could edit the question to clarify location and remove that tag?